# Is it possible to run a node.js app in Heroku every *4 minutes*?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I have an app I want to run in Heroku (the free version) every 4 minutes from like 10am-10pm Monday-Friday. I used to do this using a cron job in Digital Ocean but I'm trying to migrate over to Heroku since it's free. But is this even possible? From everything I can see it looks like you can only run stuff every 10 minutes on Heroku.

It is a simple app that sends email updates every 4 minutes.
Thank you.

Comment: There is a cron library for node, `node-cron`, or if the task can be called via API, you can use a scheduled task via windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't give you a way to run things every 4 minutes. As you mentioned, the lowest the Scheduler add-on will give you is 10 minutes.

You could setup a process running all the time, and enqueuing/processing your tasks every 4 minutes though.

As mentioned in garson's comment, node-cron can handle this very easily for you.
For example, the following code:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* */4 * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 4 minute');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Will show the console message every 4 minutes.
You can run it with `node index.js`.

So if you put the following line in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) with the name `cron` and deploy your app, you can do:

> heroku ps:scale cron=1

And the process will indefinitely, executing your code every 4 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you give any guidance for how to setup a process running all the time and enqueing/processing the tasks every 4 minutes? I don't know how to get started on that.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.